# Invalid parameter 'normalize' for estimator LinearRegression()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am implementing an example in 'Introduction to Machine Learning using Python'.

Code I am using:

```
def find_best_model_using_gridsearchcv(x,y):
  algos = {
      'linear regression' : {
          'model': LinearRegression(),
          'params':{ 
              'normalize':[True, False]
          }
      },
      'lasso': {
          'model': Lasso(),
          'params':{
              'alpha':[1,2],
              'selection': ['random','cyclic']
          }
      },
      'decision tree':{
          'model': DecisionTreeRegressor(),
          'params':{
              'criterion':['mse', 'friedman_mse'],
              'splitter':['best', 'random']
          }
      }
  }
```

and

```
  scores = []
  cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
  for algo_name, config in algos.items():
    gs = GridSearchCV(config['model'], config['params'], cv=cv, return_train_score=False)
    gs.fit(x_train, y_train)
    scores.append({
        'model': algo_name,
        'best_score': gs.best_score_,
        'best_params': gs.best_params_
    })

  return pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=['model', 'best_score', 'best_params'])

find_best_model_using_gridsearchcv(x,y)
```

The error being returned boils down to:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter 'normalize' for estimator LinearRegression(). 
Valid parameters are: ['copy_X', 'fit_intercept', 'n_jobs', 'positive'].
```

Is this error actually releated to `LinearRegression` or `GridSearchCV`?

Answer (score 2):

`LinearRegression` *used* to have a `normalize` parameter in older versions of scikit-learn; e.g. in v1.0, according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/1.0/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), the model used to be:

```
class sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, n_jobs=None)
```

but the `normalize` parameter was already accompanied by a warning:

> *Deprecated since version 1.0:* `normalize` *was deprecated in version 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2.*

Indeed, the `normalize` parameter is removed in newer scikit-learn versions; in the currently latest one, v1.3, according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), the class is

```
class sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression(*, fit_intercept=True, copy_X=True, n_jobs=None, positive=False)
```

So, what is happening is that your are following a book based on an older scikit-learn version (1.1 or older) while using a newer version, so when you call `LinearRegression()` with the `normalize` argument, you unsurprisingly get the error message you report.

Depending on your exact intentions, you have 2 options:

- If you want to stick to the book by all means, you should install scikit-learn v1.1 or older
- If you don't mind departing a bit from the book examples, you should remove `'params':{'normalize':[True, False]` from your `find_best_model_using_gridsearchcv` function

Comment: Note too the addition to the docstring for `normalize` when it was deprecated: "If you wish to standardize, please use StandardScaler before calling fit on an estimator with normalize=False." That would be the better way to modernize the script, likely with a Pipeline to streamline the addition.

Answer (score 0):

Use other parameters like copy_X, fit_intercept, n_jobs, positive and assign the values for copy_X = [True, False], fit_intercept = [True, False], n_jobs = [1,2,3] and positive = [True, False]. You will get final result of the function.

````
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

def find_best_model_using_gridsearchcv(X,y):
    algos = {
        'linear_regression' : {
            'model': LinearRegression(),
            'params': {
                'copy_X' : [True, False],
                'fit_intercept' : [True, False],
                'n_jobs' : [1,2,3],
                'positive' : [True, False]
            }
        },
        'lasso': {
            'model': Lasso(),
            'params': {
                'alpha': [1,2],
                'selection': ['random', 'cyclic']
            }
        },
        'decision_tree': {
            'model': DecisionTreeRegressor(),
            'params': {
                'criterion' : ['mse','friedman_mse'],
                'splitter': ['best','random']
            }
        }
    }
    scores = []
    cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    for algo_name, config in algos.items():
        gs =  GridSearchCV(config['model'], config['params'], cv=cv, return_train_score=False)
        gs.fit(X,y)
        scores.append({
            'model': algo_name,
            'best_score': gs.best_score_,
            'best_params': gs.best_params_
        })

    return pd.DataFrame(scores,columns=['model','best_score','best_params'])

find_best_model_using_gridsearchcv(X,y)```
````

Comment: How does this answer to the disparition of "normalize"? How does any of those options replace normalization?