# Is there any other parameter i can use in place of 'normalize' in tuning my LinearRegression model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm doing linear regression modeling and I used GridSearchCV for selecting best parameters. Below is a fraction of the codes I wrote, and I got this error

```
Invalid parameter 'normalize' for estimator LinearRegression(). Valid parameters 
are: ['copy_X', 'fit_intercept', 'n_jobs', 'positive']).
```

How to go about this?

```
def find_best_model_using_gridsearchcv(X,y):
    algos ={
        'linear_regression':{
        'model':LinearRegression(),
        'params':{
            'normalize': [True, False]
        }
    },
        'lasso': {
            'model': Lasso(),
            'params':{
                'alpha': [1,2],
                'selection': ['random', 'cyclic']
                
            }
        },
        'decisiontree': {
            'model': DecisionTreeRegressor(),
            'params':{
                'criterion': ['mse', 'friedman_mse'],
                'splitter': ['best', 'random']
            }
        }       
    }


scores = []
    cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    for algo_name, config in algos.items():
        gs = GridSearchCV(config['model'], config['params'], cv=cv, return_train_score=False)
        gs.fit(X,y)
        scores.append({
            'model': algo_name,
            'best_score': gs.best_score_,
            'best_params':gs.best_params_
        })
    return pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=['model','best_score','best_params'])

find_best_model_using_gridsearchcv(X,y)
```

Comment: According to the documentation of [LinearRegression()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), there is no `normalize` parameter there.

Comment: @Raktim it used to be there in older versions of scikit-learn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76842878/4685471